# FeignClient encode get parameter if passed as part of URL

Tags: spring-boot, get, feign

I have the following code for my FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(value = "somename", url = "${someurl}")
public interface TagServiceClient {

    @Timed("asdf")
    @GetMapping(path = "api/foos")
    List<FooTO> getAllFooForOperators(@RequestParam(value = "operators") List<String> operators);


    @Timed("qwer")
    @GetMapping(path = "api/yyy")
    List<YYYTO> getAllYYYForOperators(@RequestParam(value = "operators") List<String> operators);
}
```

How can I encode the operators of the first method `getAllFooForOperators`? I do not want to encode the parameters of the other method `getAllYYYForOperators`. I have problems with `/` and `&` but I want to handle and encode for all special characters.